# Error PLS-00103 compiling user-defined function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, user-defined-functions, pls-00103

I'm trying to create a user defined function in Oracle that will return a DATE when given a text argument containing a date substring.  I've tried a couple ways of writing this, and all seem to throw the same error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lm_date_convert (lm_date_in IN VARCHAR2(50))
  RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC IS
BEGIN
  RETURN(TO_DATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(lm_date_in, '([[:digit:]]{2})[-/.]*([[:digit:]]{2})[-/.]*([[:digit:]]{4})','\3-\1-\2'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
END;
```

the error:

> FUNCTION lm_date_convert Compiled. 1/46
>   PLS-00103: Encountered
>   the symbol "(" when expecting one of
>   the following:
>
> := . ) , @ % default character The
>   symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to
>   continue.

Any thoughts on this, and general UDF writing tips (and good references) are welcome!  Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We cannot restrict the datatype when specifying parameters in stored procedures.  That is, just use VARCHAR2 rather than VARCHAR2(50).

Just to prove I'm reproducing your problem ...

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lm_date_convert (lm_date_in IN VARCHAR2(50))
  2    RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC IS
  3  BEGIN
  4    RETURN(TO_DATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(lm_date_in, '([[:digit:]]{2})[-/.]*([[:digit:]]{2})[-/.]*([[:digit:]]{4})','\3-\1-\2'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
  5  END;
  6  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> sho err
Errors for FUNCTION LM_DATE_CONVERT:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
1/49     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the
         following:
         := . ) , @ % default character
         The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.

SQL>
```

Now to fix it:

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lm_date_convert (lm_date_in IN VARCHAR2)
  2    RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC IS
  3  BEGIN
  4    RETURN(TO_DATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(lm_date_in, '([[:digit:]]{2})[-/.]*([[:digit:]]{2})[-/.]*([[:digit:]]{4})','\3-\1-\2'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
  5* END;
SQL> r
  1  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lm_date_convert (lm_date_in IN VARCHAR2)
  2    RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC IS
  3  BEGIN
  4    RETURN(TO_DATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(lm_date_in, '([[:digit:]]{2})[-/.]*([[:digit:]]{2})[-/.]*([[:digit:]]{4})','\3-\1-\2'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
  5* END;

Function created.

SQL>
```

---

> "If you really do want a VARCHAR2(50)
>   then declare a type of VARCHAR2(50)
>   and use the type."

Declaring a SQL TYPE to enforce sizing is a bit of overkill.  We can declare SUBTYPEs in PL/SQL but their sizes are not actually enforced in stored procedure signatures.  However there are workarounds as [I discuss in this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184338/how-can-we-define-output-parameter-size-in-stored-procedure/3186780#3186780).

---

As an aside, why are you using Regex to solve this problem?  Or rather, what problem are you trying to solve which cannot be solved with TO_CHAR and TO_DATE?  Oracle's pretty forgiving with format masks.

Comment: thanks for the solution--I hoped it would be something like that.

I have strings in different forms, like '2010-08-03 00:00:00.0' that I need to process into date objects.  I guess I could use 

`TO_DATE(SUBSTR('2010-08-03 00:00:00.0', 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD')`

should I do that instead of use Regex?  any pointers on when to use or avoid Regex, and why?

thanks for the help!

Comment: If you really do want a VARCHAR2(50) then declare a type of VARCHAR2(50) and use the type.