# PL/SQL function parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

In PL/SQL, the code below will fail. It doesn't allow the definition of size for the varchar2 parameter. Do you know why? How do I fix it?

```
create or replace function logMessage(msg varchar2(2000))
return number as
begin
    null;    
    return 1;
end logMessage;
/
```

error message is

> 1/33           PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting
>   one of the following:
>
> := . ) , @ % default character The symbol ":=" was substituted for
>   "(" to continue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You fix it by removing the size constraint. It's not needed:

```
create or replace function logMessage (msg in varchar2)
return number is
begin
    null;    
    return 1;
end logMessage;
/
```

I assume your function is slightly more complicated than this?

The full syntax for the `create function` statement [from the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21642/state.htm#TTSQL291) is:

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] FUNCTION [Owner.]FunctionName 
     [(arguments [IN|OUT|IN OUT][NOCOPY] DataType [DEFAULT expr][,...])]
     RETURN DataType [InvokerRightsClause] [DETERMINISTIC]
     {IS|AS}
```

There's *a lot* of information around [the specifics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_function.htm#LNPLS01370) if you're interested but you may find [TECH on the Net](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions.php) more useful.

---

In answer to your first question of *why* I don't know and can't find an answer. But [to quote APC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3186780/458741):

> This is annoying but it's the way PL/SQL works so we have to live with
>   it.

Put simply, you should *know* at run-time how long something is going to be and be able, therefore, to deal with it. There are a few options you can consider though:

If you know what length you want message to be you can define a variable, the default value of which is a `substr` of the parameter:

```
create or replace function logmessage ( msg in varchar2 ) return number is

   l_msg varchar2(2000) := substr(msg,1,2000);

begin
   return 1;
end;
```

Alternatively, you can check the length in the function itself:

```
create or replace function logmessage ( msg in varchar2 ) return number is

begin

   if length(msg) > 2000 then
      return 0;
   end if;

   return 1;
end;
```

Comment: Won't substr() get an out-of-bounds exception if the msg is less than 2000 in length? It may be best to put it in an if statement as well

Comment: [It won't @Brian](https://dbfiddle.uk/bKq_0yKR). `substr()` will take the first 2000 (in this case) characters (not bytes for which you'd use `substrb()`) of anything that can be cast to a `varchar2` when passed into the function.

Answer (score 3):

Parameters are declared with data types but without data type length or precision. That means that a parameter may be declared as VARCHAR2 but it will not be declared with a length component (VARCHAR2(30) would not be valid).