# PL/SQL call a function outside a package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I define a function outside a package, tried to call this function, failed.

how to fix it ? thanks

```
create or replace
package body test_erp AS    
    procedure init_data is
    begin             
        logMessage('procedure init_data');
    end init_data;        
end test_erp;
/

show error
```

error is

```
PLS-00221: 'LOGMESSAGE' is not a procedure or is undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error suggests `logmessage` is not a procedure. It's a function. As functions return something you need to assign this to a variable. You know that `logmessage` returns a number so you need to declare a variable to put this return value into.

```
create or replace package body test_erp AS    
    procedure init_data is

    l_success number;

    begin        

        l_message := logMessage('procedure init_data');
        dbms_output.put_line(to_char(l_success));

    end init_data;        

end test_erp;
/
```

However, it looks like `logmessage` *should* in fact be a procedure. I assume you're executing DML statements (update/insert) in this. A function call be used in a `select` statement unless this is the case, which means that there's always the possibility of an error occurring. If `logmessage` were a procedure you can declare an [`out`](http://psoug.org/snippet/FUNCTIONS-IN-OUT-parameter_873.htm) parameter to tell the calling procedure whether everything worked or not; something like the following:

```
create or replace procedure logmessage( msg in varchar2, success out number) is

begin

   insert into logs values(msg);
   success := 1;
exception when others then
   success := 0;
end logmessage;
```

You can then call it as follows:

```
create or replace package body test_erp AS    
   procedure init_data is

       l_success number;

   begin        

      logMessage('procedure init_data', l_success);
      dbms_output.put_line(to_char(l_success));

   end init_data;        
end test_erp;
/
```

If `logmessage` isn't going to be used outside the package `test_erp` I would put it inside the package; it keeps the namespace cleaner and avoids it getting used mistakenly be another package / call etc.

Comment: No problem @user595234, If possible I would suggest reading something like [this tutorial](http://plsql-tutorial.com/index.htm), which covers the simpler stuff like how to call a function. You seem to be moving very quickly! Though I assume you're doing more than indicated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `logMessage` is the same function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282735/pl-sql-function-parameter) post:

Since `logMessage` is a function (and returns a number) you need to call it like this:

```
procedure init_data is
    i number;
begin             
    i := logMessage('procedure init_data');
end init_data;
```